# Java for-each loop says 'Incompatible Types' even though I am using generics

Tags: java, for-loop, generics, types, each

I have a `Node` class that I am using for a directed graph in Java. The `Node` class is defined as so:

```
public class Node<E> {
    E val;

    public Node(E val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    LinkedList<Node<E>> children = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

In the same package, I have a static method in main that utilizes the `for-each` loop on the children member variable of a `Node` object.

```
 static boolean processNode(LinkedList<Node> queue, HashSet<Node> visited, Node otherNode) {
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node curr = queue.pop();

            if (curr.equals(otherNode) || visited.contains(curr)) {
                return true;
            }

            visited.add(curr);

            for (Node child: curr.children) {
                queue.add(child);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

However, I get an error in the `for-each` loop:

> Error:(62, 34) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to TreesAndGraphs.Node
>   Information:java: /home/tam/IdeaProjects/AlgorithmsPractice/src/TreesAndGraphs/RouteExists.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

The children member variable is a `LinkedList` of `Node`s, so why is it expecting `Object` when I iterate over it?

Comment: What's line 62? Also: *"The children member variable is a LinkedList of Nodes"* Show, don't tell.

Comment: `Node` is a raw type. Use `Node<?>` instead.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thank you, that fixed it!